# Constructing a confidence interval question

Tags: probability, statistics, variance, confidence-interval

I'm trying to solve this question but I'm having trouble figuring how to solve it or even start
[image]

I know that the final answer is (739.8028 ml, 746.1972 ml) but I'd really appreciate any help on how to get there? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculation of the confidence interval of $ 95 \gamma $ percent is generally based on the pivotal quantity, which is a function (in this case) that depends on the random sample and the parameter of interest, that is $ \mu $ .

So the pivotal quantity for this case is $$ Q(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n},\mu)=\frac{\bar{x} -\mu} {\sigma/\sqrt n}\sim N(0,1).$$ Thus, Q is the pivotal quantity whose standard normal distribution does not depend on $\mu $, then there are $q_{1},q_{2} $ such that $P(q_{1}<Q <q_{2}) = \gamma $, for $ \gamma $ given in the interval $ (0,1). $

From the above, clearing the parameter of interest, that is $ \ mu $, we have that \ $ P (\bar {x} - \dfrac {\sigma} {\sqrt {n}} q_ {2} <\mu <\bar {x} + \dfrac {\sigma} {\sqrt {n}}q_ {2}) =\gamma $ 
For the symmetry of the distribution we can take $q_{1} = - q_{2} $
Since it is $ 95 $ percent, for the complement there is 0.05 percent that must be divided by 2, that is, 0.025, then looking in a standard normal table for 0.975 we have that $ q_ {2} = 1.96.$

$  \bar {x} = 743, \sigma = 6, n = 16.$ You plug in and find the 95 percent confidence interval.

Comment: Just a question, could you explain why the Q function gives us that Normal distribution? I didn't quite get that part, thank you :)

Comment: Q is the pivotal quantity, by definition it must depend on the random sample of the population and the parameter of interest (µ), furthermore that pivotal quantity must have a distribution that does not depend on the parameter of interest (µ).  Therefore, the standard normal distribution is taken, which does not depend on the mean (\mu).

Comment: Tobar Castro Okay one last question, do you know of a way to get q1 and q2 with probability applets? I'm trying to use the Matt Bognar applets (you can find them on Google) but I'm not sure how to find these values from the Normal distribution applet?

Comment: No, normally I just use the tables